# What is the maximum url length that can be safely used in an email?

Tags: email, url, hyperlink, truncation

My website sends out an email with a link in it.  Lately we've been getting a lot of errors that indicate that the URL in the email that we send out is being somehow garbled.  Unfortunately we dont' have any logs that indicate what the url they tried to access was exactly.  I've ruled out a number of possibilities (bad data, bad url encoding, etc)  The only thing I haven't ruled out is that perhaps the url is being truncated by our users email clients.  The URL is slightly different for each user, but generally the url will be 210 - 220 characters in length.

My question:  As a rule of thumb, what is the maximum url length that can be be safely sent in an email client, to ensure consistent behavior?

**UPDATE**

I know that there are a number of questions on SO related to the maximum URL length, but my question is specific to a hyperlink in an email client, and I can't seem to find that.

Comment: If one of your users could forward you an example of a "garbled" URL, it would probably be easier to troubleshoot this particular issue, right?

Comment: Definitely would be.  Unfortunately this particular error is handled so that it is transparent to the user.  We only realized that this issue was occurring because we logged the errors occurrence.  The logs are done somewhat poorly for this case so the only info we really have is that an error occurred.  If it helps you, the url contains an asterisk delimited string at the end.  We parse that string into an array.  What we saw in our error logs was an array out of bounds exception.

Comment: Hmm; what language are you guys using for this?

Comment: The emails are in HTML.  I've ruled out the backend as being the cause of the problem.

Comment: Seeing something similar too. Our links get truncated. They can't really be shortened because they encode a security token. Woe is me.

Answer (score 4):

**Good style recommendation for plain text emails** [*URL length <= recommended line length*]

URL should fit into a single line, single email line *should* be 78 chars (minus at least two chars for quoting in reply).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt

> 2.1.1.  Line Length Limits
>
> There are two limits that this specification places on the number of
> characters in a line.  Each line of characters MUST be no more than
> 998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding
> the CRLF